# Роутинг на локальном компьютере и сервере отличаются laravel 5.4

Tags: php, html, openserver, laravel5.4

Использую в проекте laravel 5.4,т.к файл index.php находится не в корне проекта,то в корень проекта я добавил файл .htcaccess с строками
DirectoryIndex public/index.php
RewriteRule ^ public/index.php [L]
все работает на локальном компьютере (open server),но как только выгружаю на удаленный сервер,файл index.php  уходит на место в корневой каталог и в html файлах приходиться к путю подключаемых файлов дописывать папку public/. Как это исправить?

вот полный файл .htaccess

DirectoryIndex public/index.php

Options -MultiViews -Indexes

```
RewriteEngine On

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Send Requests To Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ public/index.php [L]
```

Comment: А `RewriteEngine` Вы включили?

Comment: да, записал полный файл

Comment: Что мешает просто прописать папку public в doc root?

Comment: как это сделать? да и хотелось бы как-нибудь сделать так как правильно

Comment: уточню еще,html файлы все подгружает,не видит только css и js файлы

Comment: Как сменить document root ищите у своего хостера. Если не найдёте в ПУ хостинга - напишите в поддержку. Наиболее правильный вариант это как-раз public ставить в document root

Comment: Сменил doc root,теперь выдает 403 ошибку.права на папке верные,файл .htaccess откатил в начальным